# How to use Autocomplete MUI and OnChange in this scenario?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, material-ui, autocomplete

I have a GET API data that I wanna use to call the options for Autocomplete component of MUI in Typescript.

Given API is an Array of Objects.

```
let APIData ={
    "key1":[
    {
    "AID": 1,
    "AName":"ABC"},
    {
    "AID": 2,
    "AName":"BCD"},
    {
    "AID": 3,
    "AName":"CDE"},
    {
    "AID": 4,
    "AName":"EFG"},],
    "key2":[
    {
    "AID": 1,
    "BID": 2,
    "BName":"ABC"},
    {
    "AID": 2,
    "BID": 2,
    "BName":"BCD"},
    ],
    "key3":[
    {
    "AID": 1,
    "BID": 2,
    "CID": 3,
    "CName":"ABC"},
    {
    "AID": 2,
    "BID": 3,
    "CID": 4,
    "CName":"BCD"},
    ],
    "key4":[
    {
    "DID": 5,
    "DName":"ABC"},
    {
    "DID": 6,
    "DName":"BCD"},
    ],
    "key5":[
    {
    "PID": 7,
    "PName":"ABC"},
    {
    "PID": 8,
    "PName":"BCD"},
    ]
}
```

Using the above API format I want to create 5 dropdowns using Autocomplete for key1, key2, key3, key4 and key5. I want to store their ids for each separately on submit. I am not sure how to write the onChange for Reset function. I have tried to create separate states that will store their Ids as a list of string but I am unable to show an empty Textfield on Reset.

```
  const handleDropdownA = (
    e:
      | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
      | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
      | React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>,
    value: any
  ) => {
    const ids = value?.map((item: any) => item.AId);
    setAList(ids);
  };


<Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
                disableCloseOnSelect
                fullWidth
                size="small"
                sx={{ fontSize: "12px" }}
                //@ts-ignore
              
                options={APIData?.key1}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => !!option && option?.AName}
                renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                  <li {...props}>
                    <Checkbox
                      // icon={icon}
                      //checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                      style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}
                      checked={selected}
                    />
                    {option.AName}
                  </li>
                )}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField {...params} placeholder="A Data" size="small" />
                )}
                
                onChange={(e, option) => handleDropdownA(e, option)}
              />
```